# What does the [format] tag mean?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

What do these questions have in common?

[Change format of date with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9993560/209139)

[Talend Open-Studio Supported I/O Formats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9991884/209139)

[Convert text to image file on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9973048/209139)

[Any online tool for converting sql statements to string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9977709/209139)

Is the [format](/questions/tagged/format) tag at all useful to anyone?

Comment: This is one of those tags which makes me go \*unngh\* because the answer to your question is "hell if I know".

Answer (score 4):

I assume the [format](/questions/tagged/format) tag means any sort of formatting in general.

But as you've pointed out, the [format](/questions/tagged/format) tag is quite pointless and generic.

I can't see it being of any use to anyone, as no one specialises in general formatting.

Answer (score 2):

[format](/questions/tagged/format) is too broad to be helpful.

Some of those questions is probably using two tags instead of one. For example, [Talend Open-Studio Supported I/O Formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991884/talend-open-studio-supported-i-o-formats) could use [file-format](/questions/tagged/file-format), [Convert text to image file on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973048/convert-text-to-image-file-android) could use [file-format](/questions/tagged/file-format) (instead of [file](/questions/tagged/file) and [format](/questions/tagged/format)), and [Change format of date with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993560/change-format-of-date-with-php) could use [date-format](/questions/tagged/date-format) (instead of [date](/questions/tagged/date) and [format](/questions/tagged/format)).

If the tag needs to be removed, the questions that could use a different tag should be first manually retagged; then the tag could be burnitated.

Comment: Well, there's over 150 questions in the tag, so what should we do about it?